# $|a_N(n)|\leq \frac{c}{n}$

Tags: analysis

For $N\geq 1$ the discrete Fourier Coefficient of $f$ are defined by
\begin{align}
a_N(n)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i k/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
Suppose $f\in C^1$ function on circle, how to prove there exist $c>0$ such that $|a_N(n)|\leq \frac{c}{|n|}$ whenever $0<|n|\leq \frac{N}{2}$.
**Hint:**
Write 
\begin{align}
a_N(n)[1-e^{2\pi i\ell n/N}]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}[f(e^{2\pi i k/N})-f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})]e^{-2\pi i k n/N}
\end{align}
and choose $\ell$ so that $\ell n/N$ nearly 1/2.

**Source:** Fourier Analysis  An Introduction, Elias M.Stein & Rami Sacharchi. Chapter 7 problem 2.

I am not understand **Hint** of the book. How we prove LHS=RHS in the hint.

**My approach for proof the hint.**

If $\ell=0$, it's so clear.

Suppose $1\leq \ell< N$ and $\ell\in \mathbb{Z}$, 
\begin{align*}
f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}=
\begin{cases}
f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}, \quad 1\leq k\leq N-\ell\\
f(e^{2\pi i(k-(N-\ell))/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\quad, N-\ell< k\leq N
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-\ell} f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\\&+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=N-\ell+1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i(k-(N-\ell))/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i k/N})e^{-2\pi i(k-\ell)n/N}+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}f(e^{2\pi ik/N})e^{-2\pi i (k-l)n/N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i k/N})e^{-2\pi i(k-\ell)n/N}\\
&=a_n(N)e^{2\pi i \ell n/N}
\end{align*}

If $-1\leq \ell <-N$
\begin{align*}
f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}=
\begin{cases}
f(e^{2\pi i(k-(-\ell-N))/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}, \quad 1\leq k\leq-\ell\\
f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\quad, -\ell< k\leq N
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{-\ell} f(e^{2\pi i(k-(-\ell-N))/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\\&+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-\ell+1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i(k+\ell)/N})e^{-2\pi i k n/N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=N+\ell+1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i k/N})e^{-2\pi i(k+\ell)n/N}+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N+\ell}f(e^{2\pi ik/N})e^{-2\pi i (k+\ell)n/N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(e^{2\pi i k/N})e^{-2\pi i(k+\ell)n/N}\\
&=a_n(N)e^{2\pi i \ell n/N}
\end{align*}

Comment: Take another look at the definition of the $a_N(n)$.  Multiply both sides by $(1-e^{2\pi i\ell n/N})$

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Comment: If you have the energy, I would invite you to post a self-answer to your Question.  Spotting the way the multiplication permutes the terms in the sum requires insight, but a careful presentation of the calculation might be of value to future Readers.

Comment: @hardmath, Ok. I edited my Question.

Comment: @Radul:  Okay, but I was suggesting you could answer your own Question, below, so it could earn some upvotes. :-}